# google doc api - localhost refusing to connect

Tags: google-api, localhost, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-developers-console

I am on a windows 64-bit machine following documentation from https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/js to use the google docs api. As per the instructions, I've downloaded and installed python 3.8 (from https://www.python.org/downloads/) and have set up the index.html file with the client ID and API key placeholders replaced. After running the command python -m http.server 8000 in the visual studio code terminal and opening http://localhost:8000 in the browser, it says the site can't be reached and localhost is refusing to connect. Would anyone happen to know what the issue is? Thanks.

EDIT: Screenshot of terminal
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues and it appeared to be an issue with the default binding. This has been fixed in Python3 using the bind parameter.

```
python -m http.server 8000 --bind 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work - I've attached a screenshot of the terminal in the question and none of the commands seem to work - do I need to do anything other than clicking on the downloaded .exe file to install python?

Comment: or is it an issue I'm using python for 32-bit when I'm on a 64 bit machine?

Comment: have you tried creating a .py file and start it from there or open this server in the python interpreter. Or maybe reinstall it via "pip install http"